# How to filter number using range in tcl?

Tags: range, tcl

```
set a  [ 100 200 300 1677 ]
foreach s {
    if { 1000 <= $s <= 2000 } {
        puts "$s"  
    }
}
```

I want filter the number 1677 as output using the range 1000 to 2000 . any solutions please guide....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues:

- To store a list in a variable, either use `list`, or put the values in braces (there are other methods too, but those are the most common):

  ```
  set a [list 100 200 300 1677]
  set a {100 200 300 1677}
  ```
- You need to pass the list to the `foreach` command

  ```
  foreach s $a {...}
  ```
- The condition in your `if` statement doesn't evaluate as you might expect: `1000 <= $s` results in a boolean, 0 or 1, which is always less than 2000. So the condition is always true. Instead you should use something like:

  ```
  if {1000 <= $s && $s <= 2000} {...}
  ```

Comment: The `tcl::mathop::<=` command works in chained fashion, but the `expr` operator is strictly binary.